# ImageView in LinearLayout in Scrollview with CardStackView and Picasso Picture does not show

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, scrollview

I am developing an Android application.

I am using "com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.3.4" for card stack library.

The ImageView is in LinearLayout in ScrollView in CardView.

What I want to do is to fit the image in the card's size as per the picture below when the card is loaded at first.

[image]

And if you scroll down, it will display some texts as per the picture below

[image]

I use Picasso to fit the image to ImageView but the image does not show.

This is the fragment which has the CardStackView

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_stack, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initCardStackView()
}

private fun initCardStackView() {
    manager = CardStackLayoutManager(context)
    manager.setCanScrollVertical(false)
    manager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.Manual)
    adapter = CardStackAdapter(context, createDummyProfiles())
    cardStackView.layoutManager = manager
    cardStackView.adapter = adapter
    cardStackView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
}
```

This is the Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView
        android:id="@+id/cardStackView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="80dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the CardStackAdapter, here I crop and fit the image to ImageView with Piccaso

```
class CardStackAdapter(private var context: Context?, private var movies: MutableList<Movies>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CardStackAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.person3).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.itemView.imageView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movies.size
    }

    fun setItems(items: MutableList<Profile>) {
        this.movies = items
    }
}
```

This is the card_view which is the layout for viewHolder of CardStackAdapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lipsum"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

When I run the application, I get the card without the image but only texts as per the picture below

[image]

How can I display the image in the size of the card when the card is loaded?

---

---

### ------------------------- UPDATE ----------------------------

** NOTE: The image will be retrieved from the server not local drawable. I just used the images in local drawable for testing purpose.

I am not sure why the image does not show. But if I set the height and width of layoutParams of imageView as per code below, then the image shows up.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.imageView.layoutParams.height = 1918
    holder.itemView.imageView.layoutParams.width = 970
    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.person3).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.itemView.imageView)
}
```

So, now the question is whether I can set the height and width of ImageView equal to the height and width of `ScrollView` (`imageView`'s parent's parent) or `CardView` (`imageView`'s parent's parent's parent) **NOT** `LinearLayout` (parent) because LinearLayout's height should be "wrap_content".

---

---

### ------------------------- UPDATE ----------------------------

It seems like your solution is based on image's height and width, but I need to fit the image in the CardView or ScrollView

here is my onBindViewHolder code. I just removed Picasso.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.person2)
}
```

Here is my CardView layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/person2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lipsum"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is what I have got on my AVD. The image does not fill the bottom of CardView because it scales based on its height and width?

[image]

Comment: Problem could be `fit().centerCrop()` Since your image height is not fixed. Try removing it and try  again or try with just `fit()`. for `centerCrop` to work you need to fix the height of image.

Comment: @ADM Hello ADM Thank you for your suggestion, I have actually removed the Picasso code and just set the image with ImageView's resource property. Could you please see my last update in my questions?

Comment: I have added an answer . let me know if it works ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand from your updated question you need to to fill the `ImageView` upto `CardView` Height and the `textView` will be visible after scrolling. This Seems tricky  to with `ScrollView` because we somehow need to set height dynamically `match_parent` won't work with `ScrollView`.
I have made a Solution below see if this workout for you. Create a custom Image view and use inside `CardView`.

```
class FillImageView : AppCompatImageView {
constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {}
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context!!, attrs) {}
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context!!, attrs, defStyleAttr) {}

override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    val parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
    setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, (parent.parent as View).measuredHeight)
}
}
```

And add the `NestedScrolllView` below inside CardView

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.ace.myapplication.FillImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/hello"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="23sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**PS**- It might be an ugly solution with setting height with `(parent.parent as View).measuredHeight` but this is all i can thing of right now . love to see some elegant solution for this. I haven't tested it with `CardStackView`.

**Update**
Now with `RecyclerView` the problem is item drawn after the adapter is set and we need to listen for the `layoutManager` callback of Item drawn since.
One way to tackle this without making it complex Set the `cadStackView` height to the imageView . See the code below adding only essential code.

```
class CardStackAdapter(val stackViewHeight:Int, private var movies: MutableList<Moview>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CardStackAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

   inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageView:ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        init {
            imageView.layoutParams.height= stackViewHeight
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your fragment

```
cardStackView.post {
       initCardStackView()
   }
```

And change the dapter creation inside `initCardStackView` as follows. Also you do not have to pass Context to adapter each view has a context attached to it . Also do not use `FillImageView` in this case use normal `ImageView` in xml layout.

```
// Since you are using android:padding it will be same for all sides
    val cardHeight=cardStackView.height- (2*cardStackView.paddingTop)
    val adapter = CardStackAdapter(cardHeight, createDummyProfiles())
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but the (parent.parent as View).measuredHeight gives me 0 and do you know why please?

Comment: This is because It's not drawn yet . But you got my point . You need to give same height to ImageView . Maybe you can calculate card height at runtime with respect to the screen height and assign it to ImageView.

Comment: I have updated the answer pls check it if it works .

Comment: thank you very much for your help and I did some tweak around your solution and it worked. Thank you!!. Can I ask a quick question? Can you access ViewPager2 from ViewHolder? because I need to move to the next page when user clicks the item_view held by ViewHolder but only way I can think of is passing ViewPager2 all the way to Adapter and then to ViewHolder. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: For such case you create a listener and pass it to adapter . Do not pass any View to the adapter .

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Picasso to load a local drawable? You could just apply your source drawable to the ImageView.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/person3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Besides that, I strongly advice you to use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` and then, please, set `fillViewPort` (ScrollView's attribute) as true to extend its height as equals as the child's height

---

**Update:**

If you want to really use Picasso to load an external URL, please do the following configuration:

```
Picasso
    .get()
    .load([url_you_want_to_load])
    .placeholder([placeholder_you_want_to_pre_load])
    .into(imageView)
```

and then, configure your ImageView to fit center and preserve its aspect ratio:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried your code with local drawable. Unfortunately, it did not work. Anyway, I need to use Picasso because the image will be from my server not from the local drawable in a production app.

Comment: can you please see my edits in my questions, I just put some notes there.

Comment: Hello Bruno Thank you very much for your help, I have tried but it did not work. Could you please see my update in my questions, please?

Comment: @kisungTae man, you said you want to fit the image on your cardview (same width and same height), right?! To do that, you firstly need to move the image out the LinearLayout. Maybe you can create a FrameLayout instead ;)


And what about the text... Would you like to keep it above the image? If the answer is yes, keep the text's layout_gravity as "bottom"

Comment: thank you for reply but unfortunately, I can't change the order of imageview and textview. I am so sorry about that.